# why 'undefined' is not getting removed from Array ? Even after filtering?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
["a", undefined, "c"].map((x)=>{return x})
// this is the console output --> ["a", undefined, "c"]
["a", undefined, "c"].map((x)=>{return typeof(x)})
// this is the console output --> ["string", "undefined", "string"]
["a", undefined, "c"].map((x)=>{if(typeof(x)=='string'){return x}})
// this is the console output --> ["a", undefined, "c"]
```

I am wondering, why undefined is not getting removed even after `if(typeof(x)=='string')` check. getting confused?

Comment: *"Even after filtering?"* There is no filtering above.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) as callback for truthy values.

```js
console.log(["a", undefined, "c"].filter(Boolean));
```

For keeping strings, you could return the check of type.

```js
console.log(["a", undefined, "c", 42, ""].filter(s => typeof s === 'string'));
```

ES5

```js
console.log(["a", undefined, "c", 42, ""].filter(function (s) {
    return typeof s === 'string';
}));
```

Answer (score 4):

`map` doesn't filter. `map` maps. To filter, use `filter`: The callback's return value is used to determine whether to keep the entry. If you just want to keep strings:

```
const result = ["a", undefined, "c"].filter(x => typeof x === "string");
```

```js
const result = ["a", undefined, "c"].filter(x => typeof x === "string");
console.log(result);
```

If you explicitly want to remove `undefined`:

```
const result = ["a", undefined, "c"].filter(x => x !== undefined);
```

```js
const result = ["a", undefined, "c"].filter(x => x !== undefined);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, Crowder,, forgot to use filter method.

Answer (score -1):

use `.filter` instead of `.map`.
also read article for [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var output = ["a", undefined, "c"].filter((x)=>{if(typeof(x)=='string'){return x}});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: That's not how you use `filter`.

Comment: it will still work as in case of `undefined` the return would be `undefined` which is `falsy`

Comment: True, but that makes for rather a poor example of how to use `filter`, relying on two different subtleties: That a function whose execution doesn't end in an explicit `return value` ends up effectively returning `undefined`, and that `undefined` is falsy. Also note this will filter out `""`.

Comment: obviously there can be more optimized solutions, i just gave a solution with minimum change in existing code

Answer (score -1):

[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) iterates over the given array and returns a new one, containing one new item for every item of the input.

So your construct `if(typeof(x)=='string'){return x}`, as it is part of a `map`, actually *always* returns something - by default the value taken from the input array.

You can see that, if you add an `else` case returning i.e. "value is not a string". However you can not reduce the number of items in the resulting array by using map.

To create a new array, where the number of items is changed according to some criteria use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score -1):

You can just do

```js
var arrayVal = [1, undefined, 2, 3, 4]; 
arrayVal = arrayVal.filter(function(n){ return n != undefined });

console.log(arrayVal);
```